# Can there be a scientific explanation for an indestructible kaiju?

Tags: science-based, weapons, xenobiology, kinetic-weapons, kaiju

Assume that the kaiju is insusceptible to all weapons but nuclear ones. What could explain its impenetrable form?

Comment: Are you looking for a "how" answer or a "why" answer? The former implicates physics and chemistry and bioengineering. The later implicates evolutionary biology.

Comment: You leave a lot of stuff to explain to the imagination of the person to answer. I think this question is too broad. It needs details like, What defensive abilities does it have? What restrictions can we handwave away? What makes it impervious to normal weapons? Is it impervious to normal weapons with the destructive power of a nuke? The list goes on.

Comment: I’m sad you said scientific. I’ve got an excellent answer based around electromagnetism that also explains how kaiju can stand and move, but it basically amounts to science gobbledygook rather than anything grounded...

Comment: The hard part is explaining why a nuclear explosion can damage it but a conventional explosion with the same power cannot. The most powerful conventional ordnance has higher yields than the smallest tactical nuclear weapons.

Comment: This seems a lot like a classic "Defeat my invulnerable hero/villain." If a character (or player) is invulnerable, the *why* or *how* isn't really important...because the audience will find them boring regardless. That's why powerful villains need to do all that gratuitous scene-chewing, and why powerful heroes need weaknesses -- to be interesting.

Comment: VTC:Needs Details. We have *nothing* to work with. What is the bilogical/evolutionary basis of your kaiju? What rules of your world are we working with? What in your story is so dependent on an explanation beyond, "we've shot everything we have at it short of a nuke and nothing works!"? This is a fishing-for-ideas question. How will you judge the best answer? "Whatever tickles my fancy most" means the question should be closed. One-specific-question/one-best-answer.

Comment: They are *your* kaijus. They are protected by your Plot Armor, have your Story Strength, and are in the shape of your Creative Form. Why are you asking us? We have no idea about your kaijus, and you apparently don't wont to enlighten us.

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing science based about indestructible Kaiju, because they already defy biology by laughing at the square-cube law.

Just claim they have carbon fiber reinforced skin and impressive regeneration abilities and let suspension of disbelief handle the rest.

Edit: Additionally you could say they are made of "exotic matter" and can only be severely damaged by neutrons. A nuclear bomb is the best way to quickly deliver a high does of neutrons.

Comment: It's not necessarily true that they laugh at the square-cube law.  Sure, if the kaiju is like just a person whose dimensions are multiplied by 100, then yes it does.  But you can have very large animals plausibly that don't just automatically die because they are so large.  Look into allometric scaling for a discussion of why, but basically the idea is that "an elephant isn't just a scaled up mouse", and would never be mistaken for one.  It has adaptations that allow it to handle being so large.  It is not unreasonable to propose a much larger, but also adapted, animal

Comment: Animals the size of Kaiju's that can walk on land aren't even remotely plausible. Just dealing with waste heat alone is super challenging at that scale

Comment: @abestrange So one way to shade the lamp is to say the they are so heat tolerant that the heat from conventional weapons is just a drop in the bucket, and there's so much stress under their form due to their mass that kinetic impact is also just a drop in the bucket.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you'd need to understand what it is about our weaponry that kills things, and what adaptations that kaiju would have that would help it to sustain injuries.  Now, you mentioned that a nuclear explosion COULD kill the kaiju, which means that it is not actually indestructible, just really hard to kill.  So, what is it about the kaiju that helps it to survive?  I will focus on penetration, pressure, and heat, which is more or less how we kill things here on Earth.  I am not talking about things like directed energy or weapons that don't exist, because otherwise in your story the scientists just need to invent the "kaiju-X" quantum-nano gun and be done with it.

**Penetrating weapons** like bullets, can be explained away by the kaiju having a very thick skin.  Such a skin may plausibly evolve if the kaiju originates from a place where it is expected to be subject to forceful attacks by other creatures or, for example, a planet where (somehow) life evolved despite being rocked by meteors more or less constantly.  The latter is unlikely, so this armor-like adaptation is probably due to it belonging to a very, very aggressive species that fights all the time and has its own weapons to do it with.

Now, there are some complications here.  In short, we are **really** good at making penetrating weapons.  We can create armor piercing rounds that can pierce through a *tank*.  So the kaiju's skin would have to be thicker and stronger than a tank's armor.  This would likely mean that it has evolved multi-layer skin in addition to super-thick skin.  Basically, we learned long ago that armor made of multiple layers is better than that made of just a single piece of super thick steel, say.  As the layers break into each other, the energy from that breakage is dissipated.  This in theory leaves your kaiju susceptible to a massive onslaught of lots of tanks aiming at one place, but it's already vulnerable to SOME kind of weapon so this isn't terribly unreasonable.

How it would evolve this skin is another story, though.  See, it already has thick skin due to its fighting and biologically skin/fat/muscle fits the bill nicely for the multi-layer armor we need, but we'd also need a reason for this to evolve as armor.  It would, in short, have to have evolved to be able to withstand projectiles.  This isn't TERRIBLY likely, but let's now posit that the kaiju, when fighting each other, throw things really hard.  If they are even slightly intelligent and have prehensile limbs of any kind, this is not unreasonable.  Since they are so big, they can throw REALLY hard.

**Pressure** kills even if you aren't hit by anything.  Being next to a bomb going off, even if there is no debris, is still very dangerous to the point of being deadly.  Again, your kaiju **can** be killed by pressure, so all it needs to do is withstand some level of rapid pressure increase.  It sure is a good thing that it evolved on an ocean world and it primarily hunts by descending extremely quickly to depths of many kilometers, isn't it?  Note that it's not the pressure itself that kills us (well...), but the sudden, uncontrolled change in pressure that's dangerous.  The kaiju has to be a very fast diver to have a chance here.

**Heat** also kills, which is why we've made things like fire bombs and why nuclear weapons are even more scary.  Again, we need to remember that your kaiju CAN BE KILLED BY SOMETHING, so it just has to withstand some heat blast, not literally all of the energy possible to direct at something.  In this we are in good shape.  First, it's really big, so a short heat blast won't do much to it.  Second, it lives on a very hot planet (the oceans don't need to be made of water, after all, or it may be a hot and very atmospherically dense planet so the water won't boil away, pick one).

This has a very important consequence - its biology is primed to work at higher temperatures.  Human biology doesn't.  Our bodies must be within a few degrees (C or F...or K, really) to work.  This is because, among other things, our enzymes stop being efficient outside of the range of body temperatures we evolved to handle.  This practically means that the chemistry of our bodies stops working at certain temperatures, which is bad.  A kaiju that can already work at much higher temperatures than we can has different biochemistry that presumably is more robust to temperature fluctuations.  Put extreme hot/cold cycles on its planet, perhaps by having the planet rotate very slowly so that night is frigid and day is super hot, and you've got a plausible explanation for why its biochemistry is so resistant to heat **but it is still able to exist in colder planets like Earth**.

Answer (score 1):

You could say they are invulnerable because of rapid regeneration, but the fact that the cells are in a constant state of division makes them more vulnerable to radiation. This is the opposite of cockroaches which do not undergo much cell division and as such are extra-resistant to radiation while they are not molting.